# The Cat API - Refreshing image

Tags: javascript, image

I am using [The Cat API](http://thecatapi.com/) and I would like to change to a new image every 5 seconds without refreshing the page. I tried using `setInterval` to swap out the source, but it gets the same URL every time until you refresh. Any ideas?

```
<div id="cats">
    <img src="http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg&size=med" />
</div>

setInterval(function(){
    $("#cats img").attr("src", "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg&size=med");
},5000);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqsan8z5/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just being cached. Bust the cache like this :

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#cats img").attr("src", "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg&size=med&" + new Date().getTime());
},5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqsan8z5/1/

Comment: Interestingly enough, it's not the network request that's  being served out of cache, but that the attribute change *doesn't trigger a request in the first place* since it sees the URL is the same (at least on Chrome). Still a "cache" issue I suppose :-) +1